# Xcode programming without usage of Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have a general question for Xcode programming and the usage of the Xcode tools.
I am quite new (4 months) in iOS development and I almost never used the Interface Builder for my purposes. I always created instances programatically. My question is basically if you think i should get used to work with IB or should/can i proceed like i do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are fine with defining your UI programmatically, then I do not see any issues with that.

Interface Builder allows you to "graphically" define your interface, and this can be an invaluable tool for playing with your UI prototypes, but apart from that there is nothing that you can do in IB that you cannot do programmatically.

In my case, I see that it depends on the kind of UI that I design. When I need a pretty basic UI, the IB is unbeatable for me. On the other hand, when my UI tries to be a bit custom, then I prefer doing everything programmatically.

An interesting point is that you could use IB to design your UI, deciding on sizes and positions of your elements, and the create it programmatically.

Comment: Do you have a reference to programmatic creation of UI elements?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use IB, basically xcode having IB for ease of development, no need to setting controlls by using coordinates and each time see their visibility by running the app.

just drag and drop and at the time of making the views, you can see hows your screen going to look.

Also using IB is not a typical task so,start development using IB.